# Arrays that d3 accepts for linegraph

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js

I've got this multiple dynamic array from a database PHP request in this format:

```
array = [Object { parameter="0.7", Timestamp="2014-01-13 00:00:00"}, Object {...}, Object{...}...]
```

The dynamic parameters are as keys, and values are as strings.

I would like to use this dynamic data for a d3.js linegraph.
But I can't fit it in.

I try to transform my array in this kind of format which is close to csv.

```
newarray = ['{"key": value,..."Timestamp":value}']
```

Keys as strings and values as float or date format.

To be able to use the `d3.csv()` function I need to transform my array.

Any idea is appreciated!

My d3 code for the linegraph so far:

```
    JSON.parse(array, function(error, data) {           
                                data.forEach(function(d) {
                                    timestamp = parseDate(d.timestamp);
                                    parameter = parseInt(d.parameter);
                              })}); 

    var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 150, left: 150},      
                            width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
                            height = 280 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);              
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 250]);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));
    y.domain([980,d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.parameter; })]);  

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                            .orient("bottom").ticks(10) 
                            .tickFormat(timestamp);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                            .orient("left").ticks(5);

    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {/*ddd = d;*/ return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.parameter); });

    var svg = d3.select("div#postSVG")
                            .append("svg")
                                .attr("transform",
                                        "translate(-78,-234)")  
                                .attr("width", width )
                                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

                            .append("g")        //Achsen
                                .attr("transform", 
                                      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("path")
                            .attr("class", "line")
                            .attr("d", valueline(data));

  svg.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "x axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                                .call(xAxis)
                                .selectAll("text")  
                                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                                    .attr("dy", ".15em")
                                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                                        return "rotate(-65)" 
                            });

  svg.append("text")             
                            .attr("x", 265 )
                            .attr("y",  540 )
                            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .text("Date");

   svg.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "y axis")
                                .call(yAxis);

   svg.append("text")
                            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                            .attr("y", -70 )
                            .attr("x",0 - height)
                            .attr("dy", "1em")
                            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .text(popup_parameter);     

   svg.append("text")
                            .attr("x", (width / 2))             
                            .attr("y", 200)
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
                            .style("font-size", "16px") 
                            .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
                            .text(popup_parameter+" vs Date");
```

My click function:

```
     $('#button').click( 
                function ()
                {
                popup_parameter= $('#dropdownmenu').val();              
                $.post("klimadaten8.php",                       
                 {newname: name,                        
                   parameter: dropdown_parameter        
                  },                
                function(result,status) {           
                testString=result;                                          
              testObject=JSON.parse(testString);    
                $('#postSVG').html('');
              linegraph8();    // here starts my d3.linegraph script
            }
        );
    }

);
```

Comment: Why do you need to use the `d3.csv()` function?

Comment: That looks like a json.

Comment: @Oleg - to be honest I really don't know how to make that array d3-able. I simply can't get the keys and values for my d3 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure you're getting the data from the server correctly. That thing you wrote `array = [Object { parameter="0.7",...` doesn't make sense in JavaScript, so I assume that your PHP API provides you with a JSON-encoded array of objects, such as:

```
[{"parameter": "0.7", "Timestamp": "2014-01-13 00:00:00"}, {...}, ...]
```

If this is the case, you need to retrieve the data from PHP using the `d3.json()` function, it's very simple:

```
d3.json('your/api/url', function (error, data) {
    // Abort if some error occurred and log the error to console:
    if (error) { return console.error(error); }

    // Let's configure our date parser function which converts
    // strings like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" to Date objects:
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

    // Now we modify the data to prepare it for our chart:
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        // Note the `d.xxx` syntax because we're modifying(!) the
        // properties of the `d` object, not creating new variables here;
        // Also note the capital "T" in the "Timestamp", because your data
        // has capital "T" in it and in JavaScript property names are
        // case sensitive

        // Convert the `Timestamp` String to a Date object:
        d.Timestamp = parseDate(d.Timestamp);

        // Convert the `parameter` String to a Number:
        d.parameter = parseFloat(d.parameter);
    });

    // Now you can proceed to rendering the chart:
    // ...

});
```

See [d3.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) and [d3.time.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) documentation for time requests function and time formatting respectively.

Comment: Many thanks Oleg! I know that d3.json function. But I am afraid thats not enough. The JSON I am getting is from a AJAX request. And the reason for that is, that I am using a button click function. i added the function above to let you see what I mean.

Comment: So? Just remove the `d3.json`. What's the problem?

Comment: If I parse my first mentioned array like that ('array', function (error, data) { // and than the rendering after the each(), nothing happens. Even no error message from firebug.

Comment: That way of parsing is incorrect. Why don't you use the one in your click event handler?

Comment: Could you please specify? And is there a way to parse an array in d3 without an url?

Comment: 1) You already parse your JSON with `testObject=JSON.parse(testString);` 2) You cannot parse Arrays in JavaScript (or any other language). You can parse Strings (JSON is a string) and iterate over Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Great!
"First of all, you need to make sure you're getting the data from the server correctly."
That was the essential hint.
I've looked again in my PHP request. All I had to do was to decode my array (string) and parse my json with d3.json().

```
 $alles= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));                                 //Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable
```

Many thanks!